# Convert GMT dates to BST on the fly in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table which contains a value for every 30 minutes in a month, e.g.

```
20/03/2010 00:00    12  
20/03/2010 00:30    14
```

etc

All of this data is stored in GMT

I need to do a select on this table for the data in bst/clock time

for example

```
select *  
from tbl  
where dt between '01 April 2010' and '30 April 2010 23:30'
```

when in BST as the date range above is the dates need to be converted

I also need a way of taking the changeover hour and the end of March and October into account

Unfortunatly I cannot upgrade SQL server

Is there any way that I can do this in SQL for SQL Server 2000?

something like a function I could do?

```
select *  
from tbl  
where fnConvertToClockTime(dt) between '01 April 2010' and '30 April 2010 23:30'
```

When in GMT the function would return the exact date from the table

Cheers

Rupert

Comment: What programming language are you using? Wouldn't it be safer to let the database do everything in UTC and do the whole datetime math in a programming language, that handles this properly and sends SELECTs to the database in UTC?

Comment: Im using c sharp but I dont really want to use the language as it becomes a lot more complicated that way, I would want to do a lot with this data, like summate, loop through, etc.  Changing this to use the language would lead to a big rewrite of code.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and am investigating the use of Calendar tables for such convserions. Store all dates in UTC time then convert as necessary, I'm probably going to create VIEWS for the different time zones to avoid parameter passing but I guess a stored procedure would also work.

I found some useful information here: [how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-gmt-time](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/date-time-routines-manipulation/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-gmt-time.html)

And an associated article on Calendar tables here: [why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html)

Comment: This looks interesting, I could create a temporary table which contains all the dates between the date range and an offset then add that to the main date time?  One complication is that this data is half hourly

Comment: I'd have a permanent table, even with half hourly times that's only 175200 rows for 10 years worth of data (2 * 24 * 365 * 10). But time zone differences are whole hours, the look up table wouldn't need to worry about minutes. (I may be confusing things with this description, I'm still working through the problem myself!)

Comment: ok i will take a look.  I was thinking more along the lines of saying if I am selecting data for Feb 2000 working out the off sets for all of the hours in feb in a temp table and joining that

Comment: Yes, but why work out the offset every time for something which is a constant? If you calculate all the offsets for the different time zones you are using, store them, then join to that table. It might make your queries a bit faster. Try both ways and see what works best for you; and if you do please let me know your findings as I'll be interested in your solution.